# How does .attr method work(I don't understand the API)

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Hey there!**

I was just trying to get an id and I tried using the `.attr` method. It didn't seem to work. How does the `.attr` method(Is it a method?) anyway? Here's the code that doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="buttons">
        <div id="bgS">
        <button id="Easy" onmouseover="rolloverb1()" onmouseout="rolloverb2()" value="Javascript" href = "#">Easy</button>                              
        <button id="Intermediate" onmouseover="rolloveri1()" onmouseout="rolloveri2()" value="Css" href="#">Intermediate</button>
        <button id="Advanced" onmouseover="rollovera1()" onmouseout="rollovera2()" value="Html" href="#">Advanced</button>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function rolloverb2() {
    var jbutton = document.getElementById("Easy");

    jbutton.style.backgroundColor = "#090";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Easy').css("transition", "0.5s").attr('button');
    });
}
```

That's not all of it, but just the main parts of it. Maybe it's a sytax error... maybe it's not. Thanks.

*EDIT*: I added the function and what I'm really trying to do is change the transition of the color now.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Why do you have `attr('id')` here in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Comment: you seem to have confused a couple of things. `.attr('id')` returns the id (in this case it returns "Easy"). The usage of another jquery function (.css in this case) just after the previous one is known as chaining. Chaining can only be done with jquery functions that return the element itself. Most jquery functions returns the selected elements so we could use chaining. However since using attr with one parameter MUST return the id, it can't return an element and hence can't be used for chaining

Comment: Yes, I was. I looked at an example and thought .attr was suppose to get the id, not change it to the id... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr()` gets or sets that attribute.

If you want to know the ID of `<button id="Easy">` you can get it:

```js
$('#Easy').click(function(){
   var tmp = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(tmp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="Easy">Easy button</button>
```

What you want to do is to set the color of the #Easy element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Easy').attr('id').css({
        "background-color":"red"                      
    });
});

$('button').hover(
  function(){
     //rolloverB1()
     $(this).css('background','pink');
  },
  function(){
     //rolloverb2()
    $(this).css('background','white');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <div id="bgS">
    <button id="Easy" onmouseover="rolloverb1()" onmouseout="rolloverb2()" value="Javascript" href = "#">Easy</button>                              
    <button id="Intermediate" onmouseover="rolloveri1()" onmouseout="rolloveri2()" value="Css" href="#">Intermediate</button>
    <button id="Advanced" onmouseover="rollovera1()" onmouseout="rollovera2()" value="Html" href="#">Advanced</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets or sets an HTML attribute:

```
console.log($('#Easy').attr('id')); // Should output "Easy"

$('#Easy').attr('id', 'new-id'); // Updates id to "new-id"
```

In the case of your code, it's not clear why you're using `.attr('id')`; since it returns the string `'Easy'`, the subsequent `.css(...)` call will not work. If you're trying to *change* the ID (invoking the setter overload of the function), then the chaining call to set the CSS *will* work. If you don't need to change the ID, just remove `.attr('id')` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background color of the element that has "easy" id:

This is enought:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Easy').css({
        "background-color":"red"                      
    });
});
```

The `#` means an `id` selector.

If you want to know which button has been clicked:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.attr()` method we can get and change the value of attribute of any HTML element, for example if you want to get class name then

```
var className = $("#id").attr("class");
```

We can also manipulate the href attribute of any anchor tag like this:

```
$("#anchorTagId").attr("href","about.html");
```

In your code there is not any syntax error but the way is not correct, if you only want to change the `background-color` then you should try this:

```
$("#Easy").css("background-color","red"); //if you want to change single css property
```

Otherwise

`$("#Easy").css({"background-color":"red","width":"200px"}); //if you want to change multiple css properties.`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few quick tips, specifically regarding your code sample:

```
// if you want to get an element with the ID 'Easy', create a selector that begins with a #
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $('#Easy');
});
// if you want to set a CSS attribute
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Easy').css("background-color", "red");
});
// if you want to set an HTML element attribute
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Easy').attr("foo", "bar");
});
// result: <button id="Easy" onmouseover="rolloverb1()" onmouseout="rolloverb2()" value="Javascript" href="#" foo="bar">Easy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#Easy').attr("id")` returns the current id. `$('#Easy').attr("id", "hard")` changes the existing id to hard and `$('#Easy').attr("id", function(index, past){ return past+"money"; })` changes the id to "easymoney".